# is_int(null) is not working in switch case

Tags: php

Expect you have following situation:

```
$myVar = null;

switch($myVar) {
    case is_int($myVar):
        echo "i am an int";
        break;
    case null:
        echo "i am null";
        break;
    default:
        echo "failure";
}
```

The result is "i am an int". But I expected "i am null" as a result.

Is this a bug in php (my version: 5.5.11) or natural behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switch($myVar)` means test the value of `$myvar` against each case expression until a match is found.

`is_int($myVar)` returns a Boolean false when `$myvar` is null.

**Loose comparison** of `null` against Boolean `false` (`null` will be converted to a Boolean `false` for the comparison) returns a true, so the case is accepted

You can get round this by changing the order of your case statements to test the null case first, but

Moral: It's never a good idea to use expressions in case statements

Comment: Thank you! Understood the problem. I changed the order to make sure it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `gettype()` to identify the data type of the variable.

```
$myvar = null;

echo gettype($myvar)."\n";

$myvar = 1;

echo gettype($myvar)."\n";

$myvar = "a";

echo gettype($myvar);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/504741)**