# How does PHP's is_bool tell the difference between INT and BOOL?

Tags: php, pdo

I ask because I'm having issues passing a boolean value to PDO.

This function gives me True/False:

```
public function getBoolVal($var){
    if (!is_string($var)) return (bool) $var;
    switch (strtolower($var)) {
        case '1':
        case 'true':
        case 'on':
        case 'yes':
        case 'y':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

I'm binding data to parameters inside a function with a line like this:

```
$this->db->bind('active', (bool)$this->getBoolVal($pa['active']));
```

and inside that `bind` function is:

```
foreach ($this->parameters as $param => $value) {
    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    switch ($value[1]) {
        case is_int($value[1]):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($value[1]):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($value[1]):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
    }
    // Add type when binding the values to the column
    $this->sQuery->bindValue($value[0], $value[1], $type);
}
```

When the values are bound, I get `PDO::PARAM_BOOL` as the type when the input value `$pa['active']` is 1, but I always get `PDO::PARAM_INT` if the input is 0...

So given a 1 or 0, how on Earth does `is_bool` know what I want??? OR how can I fix this?

Comment: Since posting this, I've done away with the tinyint fields in my database. I figure that using integers is "safer" with the external data that I'm dealing with. - Happy to be told otherwise though :)

Comment: Why don't you bind all your values as strings?

Comment: This could be of interest for someone who has the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880263/is-intnull-is-not-working-in-switch-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your code as

```
if ($value[1] === true or $value[1] === false) {
    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
}
else {
    switch ($value[1]) {
        case is_int($value[1]):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_float($value[1]):
            $value[1] = str_replace(',', '.', $value[1]);//already string, pdo does not support float values
            break;
        case is_null($value[1]):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is amazingly simple and thanks also for the float addition.

I decided to use my TinyInt fields again but I had a problem - apparently PHP/PDO has a 10 year old bug with BOOLs so I simply changed your BOOL type on the second line to INT and it works for me.

Comment: It's not a PDO bug (I know the bug report you are talking about), but simply the fact that the type cast (string)true is '1'  and (string)false is '' (empty string) in PHP.